# WebApi Query String is stripped from RequestURI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi Get action

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var queryValue = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
            if (queryValue.Count == 0)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Query String Filters Required");
            }
```

I call with with this url

```
api/funds?FundProductGroupCT=favourite&pagesize=10&startindex=8
```

RequestUri always has the query string stripped.

this is my global.asax

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute
        ("default", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Why are you not just using OData for your queries?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies.

This turned out to be a bit of a red herring. I'm using the web api with in an Ektron app. I've found there is a module which intercepts the request and if it doesnt end with a "/" strips the query string.